# getMethod with an array

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

I can not seem to figure out why this is not working. plow is a constructor I made in another class file but I want to be able to assign it so that the I can later change the amount of plows by using a array for my constructor

```
                 static int PLOWS=4
                 public static final String PLOW_DATA = "PlowData.txt";


                 public static void getPlowData(){
                    Plow[] plows = new Plow[PLOWS];
                    Scanner fileIn = null;
                    int a = 0;
                    int plowID;
                    String driver;
                    System.out.println("Reading Files....");
                    try
                    {
                        fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(PLOW_DATA));
                        System.out.println("File Found!");
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error: file '" + PLOW_DATA + "' not found.");
                    }

                    while (fileIn.hasNext())
                    {
                        //System.out.println("Writing...");
                        try{
                            plowID = fileIn.nextInt(); //reading plow ID
                            System.out.print(plowID+"\t");
                            plows[a].setPlowID(plowID); 
                        }
                        catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e){
                            driver = fileIn.nextLine(); //reading Driver
                            System.out.println(driver);
                            plows[a].setDriver(driver);
                        }
                        a++;

                    }
                    fileIn.close();
                    System.out.println("Done!");
                }
```

I get This error when i run it

```
10  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at um.csc276.JavaHomework4.HW4_1.getPlowData(HW4_1.java:63)
at um.csc276.JavaHomework4.HW4_1.main(HW4_1.java:149)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this:

```
 Plow[] plows = new Plow[PLOWS];
```

you are instancing a new array of `Plow` objects. But at this point, the array will be initialized to `PLOWS` items, but all the items inside will be `null`. Each item will need to be initialized by itself.

So when you reach this part:

```
 plows[a].setPlowID(plowID);
```

`plows[a]` is null, thus the runtime exception.

A possible solution, would be inside the while block, before the try, add:

```
if (plows[a] == null) plows[a] = new Plow();
```

EDIT: as @StenSoft points out, there is another cause of NPE, when the while loop (and later the close() call) try to use the `FileInputStream`; in case the file does not exist, you just catch exception without recovering (or breaking), and just go ahead with processing: the stream will be null and you will get another NullPointerException. Move the while loop inside the try catch, then then best place to put the `close()` call is inside a `finally`.

Comment: It should be also noted that if the file does not exist (`FileNotFoundException`), `fileIn` would be `null` which `while` and `fileIn.close()` would try to use.

Comment: @StenSoft definitely that's another one

Comment: that works great! now i just have to figure out how to get that in my main function